# Can't import "android.os.AsyncResult" in built app within AOSP

Tags: java, build, android-source

I'm trying to compile an app via AOSP in build time. It uses the class `android.os.AsyncResult`. Whenever I try to make project, it stops with an error

```
packages/apps/MyPackage/src/MyCompany/MyClass.java:[lineNumber]: error: cannot find symbol import android.os.AsyncResult;
```

What I've done so far:

1. I properly added the package in AOSP tree, including its name in core.mk;
2. Package is successfully built by just removing AsyncResult class import from app source. That's causing the error during build indeed.
3. I've configured this package to be a platform one.

My Android.mk is as follow:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := telephony-common
appcompat_dir := ../../../prebuilts/sdk/current/support/v7/appcompat/res
gridlayout_dir := ../../../prebuilts/sdk/current/support/v7/gridlayout/res
res_dir := res $(appcompat_dir) $(gridlayout_dir)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)/, $(res_dir))
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --auto-add-overlay
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS += --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.gridlayout
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v4
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += android-support-v7-appcompat
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += android-support-v7-gridlayout
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyPackage
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

I suspect that apps in packages/apps can't find sources from `frameworks/base/core/java/...` automatically. But also this makes no sense, as some applications (i.e. Settings) located in packages/apps can be compiled without error using classes from `frameworks/base/core/java/...`

I'm somewhat lost here. Can someone point me a hint on how to solve this symbol missing?

Comment: Hm, may be the issue is with `LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES`? Try to remove that line, or use `LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES += telephony-common`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current`

and specify your `LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS` as following:
`LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS :=true`

Comment: The question is probably already solved after 6 years. For future answers, please also provide a little bit more context as to why you should do that. You can use the " ` " to format the text as code. So it is a little bit easier to read.